# highlight regions of no data in a Python imshow plot

Tags: python, imshow

I am producing an imshow plot in Python.

In the final plot, I have strips/columns of data, between which there is no data at all - kind of like a barcode.

At the moment, where I have no data, I have just set all values to zero. The color of these regions of no data is therefore whatever colour represents zero in my colorbar - green in my case.

What I really want is for these columns/strips just to be white, and to make to really clear that these are regions of NO data.

I realise that I could change the colorbar so that the zero is white, but I really want to distinguish the regions of no data from any zeros that might be in the data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting those values to `np.nan` ( or `float('nan')`); you may also want to pass `interpolation='nearest'` to `imshow` as an argument.